# Nano Editor over Screen in Terminal isn't fullscreen

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, nano

When I connect to a device using Screen in terminal, if I open Nano text-editor it only takes up a fraction of the screen. How do I make it fullscreen?

Comment: How are you connecting to the device?

Comment: over a USB to TTL serial cable.

Comment: I mean what application are you using?

Comment: terminator is the terminal program, screen is the program.

Comment: Does this really only happen in `screen`? If you connect to the same device using a raw terminal, it uses the full screen?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "raw terminal", but over ssh there is no problem.

Comment: No, I mean get out of `screen` and use `Terminator` to connect to the same device.

Comment: Terminator using SSH I don't have the problem.

Comment: The basic problem is that screen sizes aren't sent over serial connections, that's something that network protocols like `ssh` take care of. So you need to use `stty` to tell the device your screen size.

Comment: Using `terminator` without `ssh` or `screen` is my question.

Comment: I have never used another method to connect, is there another one you could recommend?

Comment: I'm asking what happens when you use the SAME method to connect, just without using `screen` first. `screen` has nothing to do with connecting to a device, it's just for creating multiple virtual terminals on the local system.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, this is pretty new to me. I have never connected without screen or ssh. The command I use is "screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200"

Comment: I don't recognize that way of using `screen`. It doesn't look like [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

Comment: Try using `C-a :fit` inside screen.

Answer (score 4):

Before you connect to the device, use:

```
stty -a
```

and note the `rows` and `columns` values that it prints. After connecting to the device, use:

```
stty rows <rows> cols <cols>
```

where `<rows>` and `<cols>` are replaced with the values printed before connecting. Since you're not using a network protocol like `ssh` that can send this information to the device automatically, you need to do it by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler than recording the size using `stty` would be to run the `resize` program on the remote device.

[`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) is a utility provided with `xterm`.  It uses VT100 escape sequences (supported by Terminator and screen) to find the actual screen size and does the equivalent of

`stty rows` *actual-rows* `cols` *actual-cols*

and just typing

`resize`

seems simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
mate-terminal --zoom 1.8 --hide-menubar --full-screen -e nano
```

Look at your terminal emulator, because options can be different. 
I do not know how to do it without X.